# Root Access for a Developer in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a developer that I need to give access to my Amazon Web Services EC2 instance. He needs access to the /var/www/ folder to create new folders and files.

I am not that great with the server side of things and I was hoping someone could give me a step by step instruction on how to set this up for his access?

I need him to be able to login through Notepad ++ or Filezilla.

I am been looking at security groups, .pem files and IAM Policys and have got a bit confused!!

Comment: voted for it to be moved to superuser forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the instructions on [this blog](http://brianflove.com/2013/06/18/add-new-sudo-user-to-ec2-ubuntu/)

You need to create a new user that can ssh onto the EC2 box, it doesn't then matter what client he uses.

Comment: That looks great....exactly what I needed! Thanks for that David. I will try that this evening and report back.

Comment: I was wondering, is this a terminal specific thing or can I achieve the same result with the web interface/ control panel? thanks, Kay

Comment: This is a specific terminal thing, however, being able to ssh onto the EC2 box would be vital to creating a new user, there's no way you can do this to the EC2 box without doing that.